# How do I set a script that it will run on start up in FreeBSD?

Tags: shell-script, freebsd

I am using FreeBSD 9 and I want to make a script that will check if an Ethernet cable is connected, and if so, connects to it.  I want to set it so that it runs whenever the machine starts up, or whenever I log in.  I looked at my UNIX book (It is pretty outdated, and is for general UNIX, not specifically FreeBSD) and it says that I can use crontab, but I can only do this to make things run at certain times, not when it starts up.  Can someone please tell me how I can get at this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FreeBSD's `cron` understands the `@reboot` time directive, so you can indeed have `cron` execute your script at startup. Instead of the usual 5 time fields, your `crontab` entry might look like this:

```
@reboot /path/to/script
```

If you want also to run the check when you log in, add a call to the script in the file your shell executes upon login - this could be, depending on your shell, `~/.login`, `~/.bash_login`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

On FreeBSD 11 for ARMv6 (Raspberry Pi), I couldn't get the crontab `@reboot` directive to work for the root user, and the "add scripts to the `/etc/rc.local` file" method has been superseded by a mechanism that automatically runs scripts located in `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/`.

In other words, to run a script on boot on FreeBSD 11 (or 10?) and likely newer, place an executable shell script with the *.sh* extension in this folder to have it executed on boot:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/
```

You may need to create the `rc.d` folder if it doesn't exist.

See http://www.defcon1.org/html/rc-local.html for details.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for startup script would be `/etc/rc.local`.

Comment: Though `man rc` tells "Typically, the /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ mechanism is used instead of rc.local these days but if you want to use rc.local, it is still supported. In this case, it should source /etc/rc.conf and contain additional custom startup code for your system.  The best way to handle rc.local, however, is to separate it out into rc.d/ style scripts and place them under /usr/local/etc/rc.d/."